react not rendering Header.jsx file
[header.jsxapp.jsxre](https://i.sstatic.net/eAEmStYv.png)
hello! I created this react app for the first time...and i imported/exported both the app file and the header file...both in jsx.
even though i imported them and exported as seen from the images... my react app/website is still blank...i am so confused!
I am expecting to see something in my react app...but it is showing up blank even though i imported/exported them properly

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You may not have included your header correctly in the App.jsx file.
Make sure you are following these steps:

Export the Header component as default. You did that in the header file.



import React from 'react';

function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            <h1>
                this is rendering from home.jsx file
            </h1>
        </header>
    );
}

export default Header;




Make sure you are importing components correctly in App.jsx file. The Header is a default export, you should import it without the curly braces {}. here is an example:



import Header from './Header.jsx'
 
export default function App() {
  
  // Header is a component comes from Header.jsx
  return (
    <Header />
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  )
}



here is the live example in screenshot:
Import Header Component Correctly
